# No video output after BSOD dxgmms1.sys

Tags: video, graphics-card, motherboard, bsod, gpu

Today I have paused a (GPU heavy) computer game for a couple of hours. When I returned to my computer, a BSOD was showing mentioning dxgmms1.sys.
I had no other choice than to reboot my computer. But unfortunately, I received no video output from my video card. I am sure the monitor works correctly (connected it to a laptop).

My first thought is my video card died. Under normal circumstances, my system indicates with a short beep the POST test has been completed succesfully. Now: no beep, no video output, no activity from LEDs/HDD, but fans are up and running. This all leads me to believe me pausing Medal of Honor for a large amount of time somehow did damage to the GPU.

Another horrible thought is my motherboard is somehow broken, all of a sudden. I'm afraid to spend a lot of money on a new video card, only to find out the actual problem is my motherboard.

Is it possible the game has caused damage to my video card? Is it possible the video card is actually okay, but my motherboard died on me? Would anyone be able to recommend a method or test to find out which component is actually broken here?

Specs:

- CPU: AMD Phenom II X3 720 208Ghz AM3 7.5MB
- GPU: Gigabyte nVidia 9600GT 1024 GDDR3 GV-N96-TSL-1GI PCIe
- Motherboard: Foxconn A7DA-S 3.0 AM3 DDR3 1333MHz FSB5.2GT ATX+VGA

Comment: That motherboard has integrated graphics doesn't it?  Why not pull the nvidia out, plug the hdmi into the motherboard and see what happens?

Comment: It's ublikely pausing the game damaged the card it's just likely the card happen to fail

Comment: @Paul Thank you for your reply. On the motherboard, there's a HDMI/DVI/VGA connection. However, no video output there either (with or without nVidia card). But as far as I remember, I've never gotten any video output out of the onboard connectors, even when I first used the computer.